# what is the GQL count query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql

In the interest of time, I do mean GQL, as in

```
SELECT * FROM Song WHERE composer = 'Lennon, John'
```

The following failed

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myEntity
```

also the following

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM myEntity
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass#GqlQuery_count), there is actually a way to count the return of your GQL. The [doc about the GQL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference) language shows you can't really do a count on the query itself.  So what you would do is take your select *, put it in a GQL query object, then call the "count()" method on that object to have the count