# Using App Engine Datastore Low Level API with Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How to find the total number of entries in an entity type in App Engine Datastore using Low Level API?

I there a function or filter to query for this purpose?

I am using Java to implement this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the GQL count query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27177513/what-is-the-gql-count-query)

Comment: @Patrice That link in that answer redirects to Python docs not Java.

Comment: Fair enough, but the logic would be the same. You can either use user87049's answer, or do a generic "get all entities of kind" and run a "count()" on the returned object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine has an API for getting datastore statistics programmatically:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity globalStat = datastore.prepare(new Query("__Stat_Total__")).asSingleEntity();
Long totalBytes = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("bytes");
Long totalEntities = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("count")
```

See the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats

You can get entities of a kind using `__Stat_Kind__`

Comment: "__Stat_Total__" and "__Stat_Kind__" doesn't work in local development server. Only works in App Engine Server.