# NullpointerException while querying for the Datastore statistics in App Engine Java Servlet

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-datastore

Within my app's Servlet, I want to control wether its Datastore is empty or not (the first time I run the servlet it will be empty, but that's not the case right now as I already have populated it and made it persistent) before continuing with the rest of the code. In this [Datastore Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/stats?csw=1) I discovered a way of querying the datastore and fetch different kind of statistics. 
But while executing:

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity globalStat = datastore.prepare(new Query("__Stat_Total__")).asSingleEntity();
Long totalBytes = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("bytes");
Long totalEntities = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("count");
```

I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to store the two Long variables. 
Why is the `Entity globalStat` object null after the query?

***EDIT 1***: Additional information

I'm trying to get the Datastore statistics just after populating it with a `List<Entity>` of Entities:

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    ArrayList<Tour> m_tours = new ArrayList<Tour>();
    Key tourKey;
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

    //.... some code
    private DatastoreService populateDatastore(){
        //... some other code ...
        List<Entity> List = Arrays.asList(tour,tour1,tour2,tour3,
                                     tour4,tour5,tour6,tour7,tour8);
        datastore.put(List);
        Entity globalStat = datastore.prepare(
                             new Query("__Stat_Total__")).asSingleEntity();

        try{
            Long totalEntities = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("count");
            Long totalBytes = (Long) globalStat.getProperty("bytes");
        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }` 
    }
}
```

and just this instructions the Entity globalstat object still shows to be null in the debugging tool:

[image: Entity globalstat]

how come that the `new Query("__Stat_Total__")).asSingleEntity();` doesn't produce any result when I just filled the datastore with several entities?

Comment: Eventual consistency. you put and then query RIGHT after it. It's expected. Your data hasn't fully propagated to the datastore

Comment: ok, but isn't this true only when I populate the Datastore the first time? Because I have the certainty that right now the Datastore has several entities inside (since I'm able to query it). And then, aren't the Datastore statistics supposed to be available anyway, even if the Datastore was actually empty?

Comment: you're right, if the datastore already has entities, eventual consistency shouldn't be an issue. I assumed this was a test with a "push then query". I don't know if statistics are available straight up to be honest.

Comment: Isn't there a second way of checking if the Datastore has been filled before ?

Comment: The datastore admin viewer itself. If you go to console.developers.google.com and navigate to it.

Comment: Yes but I mean during runtime

Comment: There are ways to force consistency (ancestor queries, search by keys, etc). That would be the only thing I can think of here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *ANSWER*: 
>   as reported here: [Using App Engine Datastore Low Level API with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573330/using-app-engine-datastore-low-level-api-with-java), 
>   **"Stat_Total"** and **"Stat_Kind"** don't work in a local development server. They only work when deployed in `App Engine Server`.